# Basic question about claw-free graphs and independant sets

Tags: graph-theory

The wiki page for claw free graph says if I is an independant set in claw free graph then any vertex v has at most 2 neighbors in I.  It says if it has more you get a claw but if it had 4 neighbors in I why does that give a claw as induced subgraph

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that a vertex $v$ has four neighbors in $I$. Then $v$ together with those neighbors form a subgraph like this:

```
                      o  
                      |  
                   o--v--o  
                      |  
                      x
```

Clearly $v$ together with the three neighbors marked `o` form a claw.

Comment: But I thought the claw had to be induced subgraph how do I know that is a induced subgraph?

Comment: @user99727: Because the three `o` vertices are in $I$, so there are no other edges between them.

Comment: Oh of course! Thank you

Comment: @user99727: You’re welcome.